# missing string after returning object

Tags: c++, arrays, object, return, return-value

I am trying to return an array of objects containing an integer and string, but after the return the string in the object is empty. Can someone help me please? I am a newbie.

```
CTransponder *CVerwaltung::Initial(){
CTransponder Transpo[10] =
{
    CTransponder("Chef", 100),
    CTransponder("Chefin", 101),
    CTransponder("Sekretaerin", 102),
    CTransponder("Werksleiter", 200),
    CTransponder("Produktionsleiter", 201),
    CTransponder("Angestellter", 300),
    CTransponder("Angestellter2", 301),
    CTransponder("Hausmeister", 400),
    CTransponder("Putzkraft", 401),
    CTransponder("Aushilfe", 500)
};
return Transpo;
```

Before the return, everything is as it should be, but after the string is empty.

Comment: can u say me what i have to change?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a pointer to a local array that goes out of scope and gets destroyed when the function exits, thus destroying the objects in the array.  The caller ends up receiving a dangling pointer to invalid memory, and accessing the elements via that pointer is **undefined behavior**.

Consider returning a `std::vector<CTransponder>` or `std::array<CTransponder, 10>` instead, eg:

```cpp
std::vector<CTransponder> CVerwaltung::Initial(){
    return std:vector<CTransponder>{
        CTransponder("Chef", 100),
        CTransponder("Chefin", 101),
        ...
    };
}
```

Otherwise, make the array be a member of `CVerwaltung`, eg:

```cpp
class CVerwaltung{
private:
    CTransponder Transpo[10];
public:
    CVerwaltung();
    CTransponder* Initial();
};

CVerwaltung::CVerwaltung() {
    Transpo[0] = CTransponder("Chef", 100);
    Transpo[1] = CTransponder("Chefin", 101);
    ...
}

CTransponder* CVerwaltung::Initial() {
    return Transpo;
}
```

Or, just move the array into global scope, eg:

```cpp
CTransponder Transpo[10] = {
    CTransponder("Chef", 100),
    CTransponder("Chefin", 101),
    ...
};

std::vector<CTransponder> CVerwaltung::Initial(){
    return Transpo;
}
```